# PHP regex always false

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I get from **http://server.com/edf/ghj** in php?

I tried

```
$foo = '<iframe src="http://server.com/edf/ghj" scrolling=no></iframe>';
preg_match('src=\"(.*?)\"',$foo,$m);
```

preg_match is returning `false` and $m is returning `null`.

Comment: Please [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php), and it will tell you immediately what's wrong with your regex: you forgot to add delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as @Wrikken said (and Mark-b corrected).

Just added delimiters to pattern: '~src=\"(.*?)\"~'

Comment: Totally false. it's `preg_match(pattern, string, matches)`. OP needs to put delimiters on `src=...`, not $foo

Comment: Fixed! Added in wrong place.